# MediaConvert introducing Video Audio Duration Mismatch in HLS segments

Tags: aws-media-convert, aws-mediaservices, aws-mediatailor

When I used MediaConvert to package a video file into HLS, I'm seeing that the resulting TS files have mismatching video and audio duration. For example, when I used segment size as 6, the resulting TS file has video duration as 6.006000 and audio duration as 5.994667.

How can we ensure MediaConvert produces HLS TS files with the same video and audio duration? What settings should be used?

We need to ensure similar video/audio duration as these HLS segments will be replaced with ads by MediaTailor. We are encountering few SSAI stream playout glitches, especially on Safari due to this.

Answer (score 0):

Good question.

Regarding the control of video segment lengths in AWS Elemental MediaConvert:

Video segment duration accuracy can be increased with the following settings:

Check the HLS Output Group settings /Advanced / Manifest duration format and set it to 'Integer'. Also, set Segment length control to "Exact".  This will help ensure that all video segments (except possibly the last one, which may be short due to end of content) will be of the specified duration. Related: the setting for 'Minimum final segment length' will ensure that any short final segments below the specified minimum duration be appended to the previous segment instead. This avoids very short segments which can cause playback issues on some players.

There is no explicit control for the duration of stand-alone audio segments beyond the HLS output group settings. By default, MediaConvert will pad or crop the end of the audio content to equal the duration of the video content in the input.  This behavior can also be adjusted.

Regarding the "SSAI stream playout glitches" you are seeing from MediaTailor endpoints, we suggest that you open a new support case with AWS Premium Support from your AWS Console.  To speed the investigation, please include a session ID with timestamps and/or or a HAR file browser log of the issue.